# Частичная потеря данных в 1С 7.7 - возможно ли восстановить?

Tags: 1с

Конфигурация: 1С Предприятие 7.7 типовая конфигурация Торговля и склад ред. 9.2 Оптово-розничная конфигурация 7.70 942

В меню "Документы -> Общий журнал документов " видны документы только до определённого числа. Куда-то пропали все остальные. ЗА ДВА МЕСЯЦА. Утром со слов бухгалтера были, потом пропали. Самое интересное, что в резервной копии каталога с базой недельной давности этих данных тоже нет! Откатиться не удалось...

Пробовал в конфигураторе: "Администрирование -> Тестирование и исправление ИБ" все галочки и несколько часов работы - без результатно. Хотя ранее был сбой, не совпадали отстатки, и это помогло..

Ситуация буквально мистическая: утром "все работало", с ПК ничего не происходило кроме установки драйвера принтера при корректно выключенной 1С. Файлы на винте не трогались. Перезагружался. Потом внезапно "всё пропало". Даже если предположить зловредную работу антивируса Comodo в режиме песочницы, то это бы выяснилось бы значительно раньше. А тут и резервная копия тоже без данных после такого-то числа, когда они были. Данные есть только до такой-то даты, а после нет.

Что произошло и что делать? Может в программе что заглючило? база очень старая, ей пользуются с 2004го судя по датам файлов. Указываю период - а данных нет. Но эти же данные есть по уже проведённым документам на бумаге. Т.е. они гарантированно были.
Как определить, есть ли сейчас физически данные в базе? И если да, то как сделать их видимыми?

Comment: Да, в Интервале журнала я выставил даты с сентября по сегодня, а данные видны только по сентябрь. Это в первую очередь глядели много раз. Может где ещё есть какие фильтры?

Comment: как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

**Проверьте:**

- правильно ли установлен период (не только месяц, но и год)
- не включены ли лишние отборы

---

**Как это сделать:** нужные кнопки подчеркнуты

[image: Общий журнал документов 1С77]

Comment: Нет, дело не в этом.

Answer (score 0):

Виновата оказалась не 1с а Шindows7+VirtualStore и Comodo+Sandbox.
База нашлась в c:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\1CBases\
Такие дела...

Comment: Действительно Щиndows7 во всём причина? Ну дела.